# Motors Fabric Pascal Costs an Profits

Tags: pascal

I just beginning to learn pascal language, an new on this forum 2. Forgive my mistakes and tip me how to proceed. I would like some help at the end of this algorithm in the Pascal language to write the outputs correctly, someone can pls help me on this? I´m receiving this message: Sitax error in the 37 line (last line), CPY not expected.

```
Program MotorsFabric ;
var
Production,                             { Production of types of motors}
CPM: array [1..12,1..2] of integer;      { Cost per mounth}
Values: array [1..2,1..2] of integer;     { Cost and Profit of each motor }
CPY: array [1..2] of integer;             { Cost per Year}
I,J,K: integer;                            { Auxs}


Begin
for I := 1 to 12 do
    for J := 1 to 2 do                      { read Production }
            read( Production [I,J]);

for I := 1 to 2 do
    for J := 1 to 2 do                       { read values }
            read (Values [I,J]);

for I := 1 to 12 do
    for J := 1 to 2 do                     { Costs and Profits per mounth}
            begin
            CPM [I,J] := CPM
            [I,J] + Production [I,K] * Values[K,J]
            end;
    for J := 1 to 2 do
            begin
            CPY [J] := 0;                  { Costs an Profits per Year }
            for I := 1 to 12 do
                    CPY[J] := CPY[J] + CPM [I,J]
            end;
    for I := 1 to 12 do 
            begin                               { Writing results }
            for J := 1 to 2 do
                    write (CPM [I,J]:10);
            writeLn
            end;
writeLn ('Cost per Year :' CPY[1], ' Profit per Year :', CPY[2]);
End.
```

Comment: You forgot comma after 'Cost per Year :'.

Comment: If the error turns out to indeed be just a typo, consider deleting this question, as it is not likely to be of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma:

```
writeLn ('Cost per Year :' CPY[1], ' Profit per Year :', CPY[2]);
                          ^ 
                          ^
```

Should be

```
writeLn ('Cost per Year :', CPY[1], ' Profit per Year :', CPY[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. It was just a typo error as you sad. For some reason i cound't see this. I will delete this question. Thanks again